# How do I reference named parameters in Postgres sql functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

Postgres noobie here.

I'm trying to convert a SQL Server stored proc into a Postgres function.  Currently cannot figure out how to turn this SQL line into Postgres.

SQL Server:

```
input: @name = null

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name = ISNULL(@name, name)
```

Postgres:

```
input: n = null

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name = COALESCE(n, name)
```

I'm getting the error "column n does not exist."  How do I reference parameters in select statements in Postgres functions?

UPDATE:

Definition of Postgres function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name (n VARCHAR(32) = NULL, name OUT varchar(32), description OUT varchar(64))
RETURNS setof record
AS 
$$
    SELECT u.name
        , u.description
    FROM table_a u
    WHERE u.name = COALESCE(n, u.name);

$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*REVISED: As pointed out in comments, this answer was accurate when written in early 2012, but named parameters have been supported since v9.2, released late 2012.*

Parameter names are merely decoration when your function is in [language SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-NAMED-PARAMETERS). You can use the parameters by name in stored procedures defined as `language plpgsql`.

Consequently, you must refer to the function args using $X where X is the ordinal position of the function's argument list (starting with 1).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name (
  n VARCHAR(32) = NULL,
  OUT name varchar(32),
  OUT description varchar(64) )
RETURNS setof record
AS 
$$
    SELECT u.name
        , u.description
    FROM table_a u
    WHERE u.name = COALESCE($1, u.name);
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: per @a_horse_with_no_name 's point on another answer, named support has been present since 9.2
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS

Answer (score 13):

You cannot use named parameters in a function that is defined with language=SQL.

You need to use the the placeholder $1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name (n VARCHAR(32) = NULL, name OUT varchar(32), description OUT varchar(64))
RETURNS setof record
AS 
$$
    SELECT u.name
        , u.description
    FROM table_a u
    WHERE u.name = COALESCE($1, u.name);

$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

This behaviour is documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/xfunc-sql.html

> So far as the SQL function itself is concerned, these names are just decoration; you must still refer to the parameters as $1, $2, etc within the function body

**Edit**

Since version 9.2 it is possible to use named parameters with (plain) SQL function
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS