# How to use OR in Where clause when one of its field have null value?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to query data simply like,

```
select * from product where (color='blue' or type='suv')
```

I want any particular data having "color" and "type" as mentioned in query but if i do not mention him "type" then it will get data from only "color".

For example:

```
product    color   type 
toyota      red     suv
honda       black   

select * from product where (color='blue' or type Is null)
```

In second query it return me both "toyota" and "honda".

What I need is to get product if I give its "color" value then it return data by its color only and if I give its "color" and "type" value then return data according to both values?

Comment: More information needed.  If you want just `color = 'blue'`, then leave `type` out of the `where` clause.  And vice versa.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff can you please read my comment on @xagyg post where i clearify it

Comment: Basic information must be in the *question*, not just comments. Please edit your question. Also: `In second query it return me both "toyota" and "honda".` This contradicts the displayed data. Please clarify. Finally, the answer depends on the *table definition* - provide what you with `\d product` in psql. Can be columns be NULL?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, if `$1` and `$2` are both filled in, then you want them to be treated as an `or`.  If only one is, you want only that one.

This should implement that logic:

```
where (color = $1 and $1 <> '') or (type = $2 and $2 <> '')
```

However, if your table is big, I would suggest that you put together the simplest `where` clause that you can.  So, use python logic to construct one of these:

```
where color = $1
where type = $2
where color = $1 or type = $2
```

The first two of these (at least) could take advantage of appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Either this... **returns anything that matches that colour and type, or if no type passed to the query, then everything that matches the colour**:

```
select * from product where color=$1 and (type=$2 or $2='')
```

or ... **returns anything that matches the colour and type as well as products that have no type specified**:

```
select * from product where color='blue' and (type='suv' or type is null)
```

... it depends what you want to get back.

**If both color and type may or may not be passed in and you want to use either in a query**, then this:

```
select * from product where (color=$1 or $1='') and (type=$2 or $2='')
```

Comment: actually i am using it is search process so i can enter "color" and "type" or i will enter any one of them then i will give that product accordingly

Comment: so do you mean you want this... `where (color = 'blue' or color is null) and (type = 'suv' or type is null)`

Comment: actually i think you want this... `select * from product where (color=$1 or $1='') and (type=$2 or $2='')` ... choose out of the 4 solutions which suits you.

Comment: but problem is that if i mention color=red value and type empty then it consider type as null and return me all product not only red car :(

Comment: `where (color=$1 or $1='') and (type=$2 or $2='')` will work. The AND ensures you still get the 'red' (or whatever) cars regardless of type.

Comment: how to declare "color" and "type" value as you mentioned in your query $1 and @$2 ?

Comment: i use declare @var; set @var='red' and @war; set @war='SUV'

Comment: Does this help ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771546/how-do-i-reference-named-parameters-in-postgres-sql-functions or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766657/how-do-you-use-variables-in-a-simple-postgresql-script