# Return multiple columns and rows from a function PostgreSQL instead of record

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

I was reading online about function on PostgreSQL and returns results
In this links:

1. [SQL function return-type: TABLE vs SETOF records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423958/sql-function-return-type-table-vs-setof-records)
2. [How do I reference named parameters in Postgres sql functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771546/how-do-i-reference-named-parameters-in-postgres-sql-functions)
3. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-returns-a-table/

I have written this Function:

```
create or replace function brand_hierarchy(account_value int)
  RETURNS table (topID INTEGER, accountId INTEGER, liveRowCount bigint,archiveRowCount bigint)
  AS
$BODY$
  SELECT * FROM my_client_numbers
where accountId  = coalesce($1,accountId);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Which works and return the results in a single column Type of record.
Note that might more than one row will return.

Now the response is:

```
record
(1172,1172,1011,0)
(1172,1412,10,40)
.....
```

I would like to get my results not as a record but as multiple columns

```
|---------|---------|------------|----------------|
| topID   |accountId|liveRowCount|archiveRowCount |
|---------|---------|------------|----------------|
| 1172    |1172     | 1011       |  0             |
| 1172    |1412     | 10         |  40            |
```

Is there a way to return multiple columns from a PostgreSQL function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to see it as expected with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM brand_hierarchy (id)
```

Comment: This syntax can have a performance issue. The brand_hiearchy function is called for any output column once

Answer (score 12):

Functions returning a table (or setof) should be used in the FROM clause:

```
select * 
from brand_hierarchy(1234)
```

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name! From this I managed to work it out. Having originally written my function in MS-SQL which automatically returned the results in columns, I was trying, like many newbies I suspect, to modify the actual function to produce the results, not thinking I had to modify how I asked the function for the information.  So by adding a from to my calling statement as you have detailed above, it all works.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I found this function `crosstab` I think it is what you're looking for
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/tablefunc.html